# Pointing to a wrong address for the link inserted in the comments

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

Check the first comment below, I wrote it as a test. What I wrote was

```
this is a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816530/2651073)
```

But what you see is a link to Help Center.

Why does this happen?

**Update:** I just realized that `[answer]` is a magic link, but it is **too magic**! it should work when there is no valid link in the parentheses.

Comment: this is a [answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816530/2651073)

Comment: It would probably be enough just to check for an opening parenthesis. chances that you want the `[answer]` magic directly followed by a parenthesis are slim IMO.

Comment: This is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816530/2651073).

Comment: @balpha yes if there is an space between it doesn't work, this is a [answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816530/2651073) with a space between `answer` and the `(`...

Answer (score 4):

It is not a valid link. There is some character between the closing paren and the open bracket. I am on mobile right now and thus cannot check which (obviously invisible) character it is, but as you can see in my comment on the question, a valid link works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `[answer]` having a special meaning in comments, it's a "magic link", just like `[so]` and some others.

See [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) for a list of (all) specials.

Comment: Yikes.  Let's call it a bug when it ignores a valid (link).

Comment: @HansPassant: It doesn't.